# Insert new column, increment all rows

Tags: mysql

Is this possible using only mysql:

Insert a new column and example - "pos". 
Every row in the table has to have unique,incresing value of "pos" like - 1,2,3,4,5.

In php this would be an easy job:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    mysql_query( "UPDATE example SET pos = ".++$counter." WHERE id = ".$row['id']." );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, the most efficient solution is to use auto incremental on pos.

Alternatively if your use case do not permit you, then try similar:

```
"UPDATE example SET pos = ((select max(pos) from example) +1) WHERE id
= ".$row['id']."
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it like that

```
    UPDATE example SET pos = pos+1  WHERE id = ".$row['id']."
```

Comment: do you mean this:
  UPDATE example SET pos = pos+1  WHERE id = id
This just increments all my pos rows by 1. Default value is 0 so all my rows has pos value of 1.

Comment: it will update just the row you specify with the $row['id'] not all rows

Comment: Not the correct answer - not only using mysql, but shortcut with php. Thanks for the effort, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Give your `pos` mysql field the `auto_increment` attribute - this will index it, make it unique, and increment by 1 on each insert

Comment: using mysql. Table already has auto_incremented column. I realy don't think that table can have two of them.